# Problems using multipart post request when uploading

Tags: upload, google-drive-api

I'm trying to add title info when uploading file but request not giving error and upload success still title not setting. Also when i tried to set permissions with post multipart it was not working too therefore used post json request. I can't use json when uploading file so i don't know how to handle this.

Source code (Upload method):
https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/blob/master/UploadersLib/FileUploaders/GoogleDrive.cs

I'm using this same post multipart codes for around 25 different uploading services and it only not works in Google Drive.

When i add "?uploadType=multipart" to url it giving this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badContent",
    "message": "Unsupported content with type: application/octet-stream"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unsupported content with type: application/octet-stream"
 }
}
```

But content type is:

> multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------8d110c071a9b453

So i can upload files successfully also i can set permission with json request but unable to set title.

Also i'm wondering is it possible to set permission in upload request or second request is always required?

Comment: You need to be very precise in your construction of the headers the best thing is to test your request using the playground developers.google.com/oauthplayground then you can fine tune it. Use developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads for some examples. The link you posted is dead, so there is not enough information to post a solution

Comment: Just used multipart/related protocol because API was not supporting multipart protocol properly. There was no problem in headers or multiparts creation because more than 40 uploaders was using these codes. I don't understand why it was requiring multipart/related and creating too much work to us too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead i used https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileid} for set title and parents.

This require second request but have no choice, because can't set metadata while uploading.